# Булевая функция без return'a возвращает корректное значение

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю в QT 6.2
Есть у меня программа, что считает площадь произвольного простого многоугольника. Перед расчётом площади, я проверяю многоугольник на пересечение сторон.

```
if(!cross(polygon, n))
{
    double S = square(polygon,n);
    if(!(qIsInf(S)))
    {
        ui->l_Sq->setText("Площадь: " + QString::number(S));
    }
    else
    {
        warning("Многоугольник слишком большой(");
    }
}
else
{
    warning("Я умею работать только с простыми многоугольниками(");
}
```

Для этого я вызываю булевую ф-цию `not_cross()`

```
bool cross(double **polygon, int n = 0) // Ф-ция  проверки на пересечение сторон многоугольника
{
    bool not_cross = true;
    double x1,x2,x3,x4;
    double y1,y2,y3,y4;
    double v1,v2,v3,v4;

    for (int i=0; i<n&&not_cross; i++)
    {
        int k = (i+1)%n;
        x1 = polygon[i][0]; x2 = polygon[k][0];
        y1 = polygon[i][1]; y2 = polygon[k][1];
        for (int j = 0; j<n&&not_cross; j++)
        {
            int m = (i+j)%n;
            int v = (m+1)%n;
            if(abs(i-m) <= 1)
                continue;
            x3 = polygon[m][0]; x4 = polygon[v][0];
            y3 = polygon[m][1]; y4 = polygon[v][1];

            v1 = (x4-x3)*(y1-y3)-(y4-y3)*(x1-x3);
            v2 = (x4-x3)*(y2-y3)-(y4-y3)*(x2-x3);
            v3 = (x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x3-x1);
            v4 = (x2-x1)*(y4-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x4-x1);

            not_cross = !((v1*v2<0) && (v3*v4<0)) && not_cross;

        }
    }
}
```

Как можно заметить, в этой ф-ции отсутствует `return`. Однако она всё ещё возвращает корректные значения. Tо есть, если фигура пересекается, то она вернёт `true`, если не пересекается -- `false`
Вроде бы, я достаточно раз протестировал работу программы, чтобы исключить совпадения.
С чем это связанно? Неужели компилятор сам догадывается вернуть значение `not_cross`? Хотя если дописать возращение, то придётся написать `return !not_cross`
(Да, я тут нагородил кода. Простите, я писал в спешке)

Comment: *"Как можно заметить, в этой ф-ции отсутствует return. Однако она всё ещё возвращает корректные значения."* - ничего подобного *"Вроде бы, я достаточно раз протестировал работу программы, чтобы исключить совпадения."* - никакое тестирование программы не позволит утверждать, что она возвращает корректные значения

Comment: Конечно, конечно. Никто и не сомневается. Но, учитывая кол-во проверок, сложно поверить, что это случайные совпадения

Comment: ¿И какое это количество? В вопросе никаких проверок не приведено, ни ссылки на онлайн компилятор нет. Мне вот например вообще сложно поверить, что этот код мог собираться. Разве что вы намеренно игнорировали доступные диагностики компилятора.

Comment: @user7860670 Работал в QT. Так что вряд ли найдётся онлайн компилятор. Но, если хотите, могу записать вам видео.

Comment: Приведенная функция не содержит никаких привязок к QT. Собственно QT в тегах - лишнее. *" могу записать вам видео"* - вместо этого надо составить [mcve], причем обратите внимание, что "воспроизводимый" означает воспроизводимость прежде всего у читателей вопроса, а то часто бывает
 что спрашивающий вопрос находится в шестом состоянии

Comment: более того, с Qt можно "работать" с разными компиляторами, поведение которых при отсутствии return отличается

Answer (score 4):

Формально, *функция без return, которая возвращеет не void*, другими словами, функция, выполнение которой доходит до последней скобки, не встречая на своем пути `return (что-то)`, вызывает *неопределенное поведение*.

*Неопределенное поведение* может быть и таким, какого вы ожидаете, но программа при этом остается некорректной.

Comment: Хорошо. Однако мне всё ещё непонятно, почему у этой ф-ци есть булевое значение, которое ещё и совпадает с корректным значением так часто, что я при проверке на нескольких пк (дома, в ВУЗе, своими руками, руками преподавателя) данная ошибка не дала о себе знать

Comment: Надо посмотреть ассемблерный листинг. Вероятно, компилятор засовывает вычисленное значение в регистр EAX, а потом интерпретирует EAX как  возвращенное значение. Так что это просто удачное совпадение.

Comment: Похоже на то. Однако, получается что он ещё и накладывает отрицание на булевое значение. Хотя, я щас переписал ф-цию так cross = ((v1*v2<0) && (v3*v4<0)) || cross; соотвественно, если она наложит отрицание, то и значение будет некорректным. И самое главное, что если опять забыть про return, то она всё ещё правильно работает. Как-то много совпадений

Comment: @BITniki, не понимаю вашего акцентирования внимания на «совпадениях». Хотите выходить из функций без `return`? Так выходите. Кто же вам запретит. Только потом не говорите, что вас не предупреждали.

Comment: Просто хотелось узнать, почему именно не вылезла ошибка.